# Best way to filter references to static files out from a list of URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

Objective: I'm building a web-crawler / spider in NodeJS.

Example: I have the following strings:

```
'https://index.hu/assets/static/indexnew_css/public/global.css?v=1523632680'
'http://ogp.me/ns/fb'
```

I would like to filter the first one, because it's a static .css file. I could use a regex that matches .css .js .svg (etc) but that would also filter out some links that would be valid references to other websites.

The other option I have thought about is removing all `script` and `style` elements from the html before parsing it for URL-s.

Any better options to do this?

Comment: Does it matter to you that `'http://ogp.me/ns/fb'` could be a static file too, for example, being the same as `'http://ogp.me/ns/fb/index.html'`?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter. I just want to filter out non-html documents to avoid wasting resources parsing the responses.

Comment: but what about javascript files that load html files ? (more or less what happens in many web-apps and other "single page applications")

Comment: I'm ignoring them for now, as using a virtual DOM would take a lot of resources.

Maybe I should just filter out url-s ending in .js/.css and then only accept content-type text/html?

Comment: The content-type filtering that would a sensible approach IMHO, but you would have to request every URL anyway to know that, that might not fit your need. In addtition, if you remove every <script> tag that might save you some resources.

Comment: You can use the new URL api for better filtering. `urlArray.filter((e)=>!(new URL(e).pathname.match(/\.(js|css)$/)))`